# Message are recieved from GCM server but could be handled only while application running

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

I ran a sample where registered my device at my backend which send back to the device message via GCM. The issue is that I could receive those messages at BroadCastreceiver.OnReceive method while app is app and running but NOTHING happens if I exit my app and send a push again.

Do I need additional implementation to have push displayed by Android system in native way (like iOS & Windows Phone do).

I followed this guide and there is nothing about native Android OS notifications:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

ps:
when I'm sending a message while my client app is closed I'm still getting success response:

```
{"multicast_id":5388850153658301208,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1382683020113430%1a3104c7f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

update 1:
manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:installLocation="auto" 
          package="com.pushtest.droid" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1">

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

  <permission android:name="com.pushtest.droid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.pushtest.droid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

  <application android:label="push droid">
    <receiver android:name="com.pushtest.droid.MyGcmBroadcastReceiver"
              android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gcm.intent.RETRY" />

        <category android:name="com.pushtest.droid" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code and Manifest file.

Comment: Just added. And as I say before device is registered and pushes are delivered while app is running so I think there is no issues with manifest. I think I'm missing some concept understand of GCM

Comment: You will receive message from GCM either your application running or not. but you can handle next process after receive message.

Comment: Where have you declared GCMIntentService in your manifest file???

Comment: is it required to receive a push when app if not running? I tried to comment it and run my push processing without it (supposed that system will handle it by itself when app is not running)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I missed the fact that in Android you have to show PUSH notification by yourself.
So I have implemented handling logic as follow and now I can see my notifications when push arrives even WITHOUT IntentService (sorry for syntax and it is monodroid, but concept in java is the same) :

```
private void HandleMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{
   var extras = intent.Extras;
   string message = extras.GetString("message");
   string title = extras.GetString("title");
   var notif = new Notification(Resource.Drawable.Icon, title);
   notif.Flags |= NotificationFlags.AutoCancel;
   notif.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate;
   var notificationIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(Activity1));
   notificationIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
   var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
   notif.SetLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, contentIntent);
   var mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
   mNotificationManager.Notify(1, notif);
}
```